# awk full join 2 files on single column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have 2 CSV files of which i want to join together using AWK.

file1.csv:

```
A1,B1,C1
"apple",1,2
"orange",2,3
"pear",5,4
```

file2.csv:

```
A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,3,4
"peach",2,3,3
"pear",5,4,2
"mango",6,5,1
```

This is the output i want:

```
A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,2,"apple",1,3,4
"orange",2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
"pear",5,4,"pear",5,4,2
NULL,NULL,NULL,"peach",2,3,3
NULL,NULL,NULL,"mango",6,5,1
```

I want to do a full join on file 1 and file2 where A1=A2. File2 has more rows than file1.  For records that dont have matching column values, NULL values will be inserted instead.

Comment: yes but im not sure how

Answer (score 3):

Can use standard [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) utility for simplicity.

note: join requires sorted input, so solution must first sort inputs

**sample join**

```
tail -n +2 file1.csv | sort -k 1 1>file3.csv;
tail -n +2 file2.csv | sort -k 1 1>file4.csv;
paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | head -n 1 1>output.txt;
join -a 1 -a 2 -t , -e NULL -1 1 -2 1 \
     -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 \
     file3.csv file4.csv 1>>output.txt;
```

**outputs**

```
A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,2,"apple",1,3,4
NULL,NULL,NULL,"mango",6,5,1
"orange",2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
NULL,NULL,NULL,"peach",2,3,3
"pear",5,4,"pear",5,4,2
```

Comment: what does the -a mean?

Comment: the `-a 1` flag tells join to keep all fields from first input ( similar for `-a 2` ). this is needed in addition with `-e NULL` to get the desired output

Comment: For the name of **simplicity**, it is running 3 commands, creating 2 temporary files and changing the original order of output.

Comment: @anubhava correct - though to some this solution is more intuitive and easier to maintain ( if this is in ongoing usage ). depends on what OP is after

Comment: How can you keep the header as well?

Comment: modified to retain the headers

Comment: Thanks, if only the first row is the header, why not +1 instead of +2?

Comment: `-n +K` outputs lines starting with the Kth. +2 to start with second line onwards

Comment: Needs a -k for both the sort statements: `sort -k 1`  Could you also explain why theres an extra `1` after `head -n 1 1`  and  here `1>>output.txt;`. Additionally, when I run the paste statement: `paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | head -n 1 1>output.txt;` my header looks like this: `1,B1,C1,2,D2,E2,F2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81814/discussion-between-jxn-and-amdixon).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{if (NR==1)print "A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2";next} 
         FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}
         {print $0 FS (($1 in a)? a[$1]:"NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL"); delete a[$1]}
         END{for (i in a) print "NULL,NULL,NULL," a[i]}' file2.csv file1.csv
A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,2,"apple",1,3,4
"orange",2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
"pear",5,4,"pear",5,4,2
NULL,NULL,NULL,"mango",6,5,1
NULL,NULL,NULL,"peach",2,3,3
```

Comment: Can you explain what this part mean?: `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}` and why there is a delete at the end `delete a[$1]`

Comment: `FNR==NR` means execute the next block for first input file i.e. `file2.csv`. `a[$1]=$0` populates an array `a` with key as `$1` (first field) and value is `$0` or full row of first file. `delete a[$1]` removes processed keys from array `a` so that remaining rows can be printed in `END` block i.e. `mango` and peach` records from `file2.csv`.

Comment: Thanks. after running it gave me the `>` input. Is something missing?

Comment: Also if you're getting a different output due the different input files then provide those files in question so that I can look into that and tweak the answer (if needed).

Comment: thanks, my new input file1 has 4 cols and input file2 has 8 cols. I thought the only things to change are the printing of more col names and 4 more null values in the second line to make 8, and 1 more in the third line to make 4 nulls.

Comment: Can you update the question with your new input files and expected output so that I can investigate this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81837/discussion-between-jxn-and-anubhava).

Comment: Try this command: `awk -F, 'FNR==1{if (NR==1)print "search,sum_binary,frequency,score,search2,freq,visit,pdp,startpage,median,bounce,con";next} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} {print $0 FS (($1 in a)? a[$1]:"NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL"); delete a[$1]} END{for (i in a) print "NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL," a[i]}' file2.csv file1.csv`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{flag=2}NR==FNR{if(flag==2){head=$0;--flag;}else{a[$1]=$0}}
NR>FNR{if(flag==1){print head","$0;flag=0}else{if(a[$1]){print a[$1],$0;delete a[$1]}
else{print "NULL,NULL,NULL,"$0}}}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]){print a[i]",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL"}}}' 
file1.csv file2.csv
```

the output:

```
A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,2 "apple",1,3,4
NULL,NULL,NULL,"peach",2,3,3
"pear",5,4 "pear",5,4,2
NULL,NULL,NULL,"mango",6,5,1
"orange",2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: This works! However, when i use it on files of larger sizes, they were concatenated incorrectly on some columns. so i had to put OFS="," before every print statement and it got resolved.

Comment: @jxn  It's right. Using `OFS=","` is much better and robuster.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, a bash script can also tackle the job with some limitations. The following works fine for the example, but expects matching rows on the same row in each of the input files. If that isn't the case with the csv file, then a simple pre-sort of the files will be required.

This was more an exercise than a contender, but ended up satisfying the conditions in the same or better order than some of the other solutions. If you have any questions, let me know:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i l1=0   # lines in file 1
declare -i l2=0   # lines in file 2
declare -i a1s=0  # array 1 stride
declare -i a2s=0  # array 2 stride

while read -r line; do              ## fill array from file1
    a1+=( $(tr ',' ' ' <<<$line) )
    ((l1++))
done <"$1"

while read -r line; do              ## fill array from file2

    a2+=( $(tr ',' ' ' <<<$line) )
    ((l2++))

done <"$2"

a1s=$((${#a1[@]}/l1))   ## stride of array 1
a2s=$((${#a2[@]}/l2))   ## stride of array 2

[ $l1 -lt $l2 ] && lim=$l1 || lim=$l2   ## which has more rows?

for ((i = 0; i < lim; i++)); do         ## for common rows
    if [ $i -eq 0 -o ${a1[$((i*a1s))]} = ${a2[$((i*a2s))]} ]; then
        for ((j = 0; j < a1s; j++)); do
            [ $j -eq 0 ] && printf "%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]} || printf ",%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]}
        done
        for ((j = 0; j < a2s; j++)); do printf ",%s" ${a2[$((i*a2s+j))]}; done
        printf "\n"
    else
        for ((j = 0; j < a1s; j++)); do
            [ $j -eq 0 ] && printf "%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]} || printf ",%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]}
        done
        for ((j = 0; j < a2s; j++)); do printf ",NULL"; done
        printf "\n"
        for ((j = 0; j < a1s; j++)); do
            [ $j -eq 0 ] && printf "NULL" || printf ",NULL"
        done
        for ((j = 0; j < a2s; j++)); do printf ",%s" ${a2[$((i*a2s+j))]}; done
        printf "\n"
    fi
done

if [ $l1 -lt $l2 ]; then    ## for excess rows (longest row-wise)
    last=$l2
    for ((i = lim; i < last; i++)); do
        for ((j = 0; j < a1s; j++)); do
            [ $j -eq 0 ] && printf "NULL" || printf ",NULL"
        done
        for ((j = 0; j < a2s; j++)); do printf ",%s" ${a2[$((i*a2s+j))]}; done
        printf "\n"
    done
else
    last=$l1
    for ((i = lim; i < last; i++)); do
        for ((j = 0; j < a1s; j++)); do
            [ $j -eq 0 ] && printf "%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]} || printf ",%s" ${a1[$((i*a1s+j))]}
        done
        for ((j = 0; j < a2s; j++)); do printf ",NULL"; done
        printf "\n"
    done
fi

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash ../read2redir.sh A1.txt A2.txt
A1,B1,C1,A2,D2,E2,F2
"apple",1,2,"apple",1,3,4
"orange",2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
NULL,NULL,NULL,"peach",2,3,3
"pear",5,4,"pear",5,4,2
NULL,NULL,NULL,"mango",6,5,1
```